# How to filter python pandas dataframe column by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am having problems filtering a pandas dataframe - I want to filter all the dates in the "Date" column to return only dates in the last month, but python is mixing up the date and month and returning the wrong answer.  Could you let me know how to fix thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("Dates.csv"))
tday = dt.date.today()
tdelta = dt.timedelta(days=-30)
dt = tday + tdelta
dt = np.datetime64(dt)
print(dt)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.loc[df['Date'] >= dt]
print(df)
```

`Dates.csv` df is:

```
DF = 
     Met By        Date
0    David   06/07/2020
1    Philip  22/06/2020
2   Richard  02/04/2020
3   Richard  09/03/2020
4   Richard  17/02/2020
5    Philip  12/02/2020
6    Philip  29/01/2020
7      Jane  20/01/2020
8      Jane  13/01/2020
9   Richard  10/01/2020
10   Philip  06/01/2020
```

UPDATE: solved by VALDI - must include dayfirst = True on read_csv

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Dates.csv", parse_dates=[1], dayfirst = True)
df = df[df['Date'] > pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta('30D')]
print(df)
```

Comment: You can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642201/how-can-i-sort-dataframe-by-date-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort DataFrame by date in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642201/how-can-i-sort-dataframe-by-date-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the way how you read your DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("Dates.csv"))
```

Note that:

- `pd.read_csv` already returns a DataFrame,
- so there is no need to create **another** *DataFrame* from the first one.

A simpler approach is: `df = pd.read_csv("Dates.csv")`.

But this is not all. If you have a column containing a date then convert it
to *datetime* type as early as when your read the DateFrame, so, assuming that
your file contains only *Met By* and *Date* columns (no index column),
the proper formula to read is:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Dates.csv", parse_dates=[1])
```

And now how to filter your DataFrame:

The first hint is **not** to use *datetime* module, as *Pandas* has its native
*today* and *Timedelta* functions.
As *Date* column is now of proper (*datetime*) type, you don't need any conversions.
Just use:

```
df[df.Date > pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta('30D')]
```

If you have also **future** dates and want to filter them out, run:

```
df[df.Date > (pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta('30D'))
    and df.Date < pd.Timestamp.today()]
```

Comment: hi i am using your code: df = pd.read_csv("Dates.csv", parse_dates=[1])                                               df = df[df['Instruction Date'] > pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta('30D')]
- but it is still returning "3  Richard       2020-09-03 5   Philip       2020-12-02 9  Richard       2020-10-01" as values - when it should not return any. lmk if there is a way to fix this thanks

Comment: also if i add this i get same problem - df['Instruction Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Instruction Date'], format='%Y/%m/%d')

Comment: Your data sample contains only **past** dates, so I didn't think about **future** dates. Now I corrected this detail.

Comment: Hi Valdi - this is not a future date - it is returning me "3   Richard  09/03/2020" - the third row in the data sample - and it is swapping the date with the month - which means it is not returning the right responses.  Do you know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Pass also *dayfirst=True* to *read_csv*. As I remember, the default value is *False*, so day / month are swapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas's `to_timedelta` function and datetime's `datetime.now` function on date column like

It seems you need to reformat date first

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

then

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd 


df_filtered = df[df.Date > datetime.datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("30day")]
```

As suggested by @Henry, you can use `pd.Timestamp.now()` as well

```
df_filtered = df[df.Date > pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.to_timedelta("30day")]
```

Comment: Or just use `pd.Timestamp.now()`.

Comment: @HenryYik, great, thanks for reminding, added to the answer

Comment: hi still have same problem after below - python still confusing date with month

Comment: can you eloborate more about what do you mean by confusing betwwen date with month, may be put desired and current output

Comment: say timestamp is : 2020-07-29, python will return dates including 2020-09-03 - however this is supposed to be ninth of march, not third of september

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you try to reformat first? @DavidA

Comment: hi have done this - df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')     
but it still makes no difference. Doesnt make any sense.  I found your linkedin on your profile, if you like I can add you, send you full code, then give you endorsement when you figure it out? thanks

Comment: I just executed you code and it works fine, you just dont have any date greater than 29/07 which is one month delta

Comment: (i dont get any row in filtered_df as all are before one month delta)