# x-axis values are not ordered when plotting graphs with pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to plot multiple graphs using python... but I get some issues with x-axis values that are not ordered in a correct way.

I used this code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Userscsv_grouped.csv',sep=';')
for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'JOUR(PSDATE)' and col != 'GNODEB':
        plt.style.use('seaborn')
        pivoted_df=df.pivot(index='JOUR(PSDATE)',columns='GNODEB', values='RACH_MSG2_SR')
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        pivoted_df.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', legend=True)

        ax.set_xlabel('JOUR(PSDATE)')
        ax.set_ylabel(col)
        ax.set_title(f'Evolution of {col} by GNODEB')
        plt.legend(title='GNODEB', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
        plt.show()
        break
```

Here is the result I get:
[image]

Comment: [Related/Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642201/how-can-i-sort-dataframe-by-date-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Right now your index is of type string - pandas doesn't know that it should be interpreted as dates. Try explicit conversion with `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Userscsv_grouped.csv',sep=';')
for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'JOUR(PSDATE)' and col != 'GNODEB':
        plt.style.use('seaborn')
        pivoted_df=df.pivot(index='JOUR(PSDATE)',columns='GNODEB', values='RACH_MSG2_SR')
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        pivoted_df.index = pd.to_datetime(pivoted_df.index, format="DD/MM/YYYY")
        pivoted_df.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', legend=True)

        ax.set_xlabel('JOUR(PSDATE)')
        ax.set_ylabel(col)
        ax.set_title(f'Evolution of {col} by GNODEB')
        plt.legend(title='GNODEB', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
        plt.show()
        break
```

Comment: Hello Maria ...... I tried your solution and firstly get an errour of    time data '01/02/2023' does not match format 'DD/MM/YYYY' then tried this format :                                                 format='%d/%m/%Y'                                                                                                                            and it worked . Thank You alooooot