# Best way to read a csv (* without a header *) sort and store back to disk

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file with four columns (no header). I would like to sort the file
by the first, then second column, and store back to disk.

I can read the file in using pandas or numpy, no problem, but not sure how to sort it, and store.

Comment: can't you sort it directly on excel or similar?!

Comment: @leoschet yes, probably, but I want to know how to do this programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns)

Comment: what've you tried? quick search gives me: [pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just like you wanted to process:

1. [read / parse CSV into a DF](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
2. [sort DF](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
3. [export DF to CSV and write it to disk](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

If we chain all steps together, then we don't even need to create a variable for the DataFrame...

---

Demo:

```
(pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', header=None)
   .sort_values([0,1])
   .to_csv('/path/to/result.csv', index=False, header=None))
```

Comment: @kmario23, it's a fair point. I've added a short explanation...