# How to configure the X label intervals in Line Graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Similar to [Ploting Time Series Data with all the time stamp labeled in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878072/ploting-time-series-data-with-all-the-time-stamp-labeled-in-python?noredirect=1#comment100318921_56878072)

The data set has Time Stamp to 30 Second Resolution, When Ploting, how to specify to mark a X label in every hourly interval.

[image: img]

[image: img]

Comment: do not post images of the dataset. Post the data itself. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then modify your question please.

Answer (score -1):

Use [xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html).

```
times = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, ...]
filtered_times = times[::120] # Skip 60 minutes at a time
xticks(filtered_times, map(str, filtered_times))
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is ticks,**kwargs, and what is times = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, ...] .. Could we use time = df.index.values ?
I got ticks not defined error.

Comment: times is an array containing the sorted time values in seconds. Yes, if it is sorted and in seconds.

Comment: You can ignore **kwargs. It's just a way to take keyword arguments like plt.plot(x, y, size=2)

Comment: Lets say if I have 5 hours data, then I need to populate time [0,30,60,..... till 60*60*5]  is it. ?

Comment: Yeah. If the data is already in the dataframe, then you can sort it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column