# Sort Excel worksheet based on a column using python

Tags: python, excel, sorting

How do I sort the excel worksheet  based on the 'Name Column' by using python

like MS Excel sort by select a column and sort 'A-Z' sorting.

[image]

**Expected ouput:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue,

```
        0          1     2
0   354.7      April   4.0
1    55.4     August   8.0
2   176.5   December  12.0
3    95.5   February   2.0
4    85.6    January   1.0
5     152       July   7.0
6   238.7       June   6.0
7   104.8      March   3.0
8   283.5        May   5.0
9   278.8   November  11.0
10  249.6    October  10.0
11  212.7  September   9.0

df.sort_values('2')
```

[how to sort pandas dataframe from one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column)