# how can we use sort_value?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

```
                                                    rating          
                                                     size      mean
title                                                              
'Til There Was You (1997)                               9  2.333333
1-900 (1994)                                            5  2.600000
101 Dalmatians (1996)                                 109  2.908257
12 Angry Men (1957)                                   125  4.344000
187 (1997)                                             41  3.024390
```

How can i sort based on mean column?

Comment: What type is the data, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @mazdak dalkoohi you use pandas data frame?

Comment: [Sort Pandas Dataframe by a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column)

Answer (score 0):

As it is a MultiIndex DataFrame, you could do:

```
>>> df.sort_values([('rating', 'mean')])
```