# pandas sort by row value

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new to pandas (working with 3rd party code, forced to use it!), and I have a dataframe which looks like so:

```
name_id    cookie_id    file_name_id
John       56           /some/loc
Doe        45           /some/loc2
John       67           /some/loc3
hilary     768          /some/loc4
wendy      8            /some/loc3
hilary     4            /some/loc4
```

I would like to sort them by the `name_id` like so:

```
name_id    cookie_id    file_name_id
Doe        45           /some/loc2
John       56           /some/loc
John       67           /some/loc3
hilary     768          /some/loc4
hilary     4            /some/loc4
wendy      8            /some/loc3
```

I am looking at:

```
df.sort_values(by=['name_id'])
```

and it does seem to give me the correct answer, but since I am new to pandas, I am afraid there might be some gotchas I need to aware of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to sort pandas dataframe from one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column)

Answer (score 1):

`df.sort_values(by=['name_id'])` should be perfectly fine to use. Watch out for spaces in the beginning of the `name_id` string as those would be sorted first. For example, `" wendy"` would be placed in the top in your case.