# how do i sort a file second column in python code

Tags: python, command-line

This is my text file. I want to sort second column by ascending order. How do I sort this in python code?

*Test file content:*

```
ghj sfs
dtj fsf
zzz hdh
abc kdk
bcd jdd
csf jkd
sfa aaa
ser jld
afr zzz
awr kld
fas ljl
afr lfl
faw kks
```

Comment: Read it as a pandas dataframe and sort it with `sort_values()`. Does this answer your question? [how to sort pandas dataframe from one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column)

Comment: **1.** Read file content. **2.** Sort lines in ascending order using `sorted()` with custom `key` argument. **3.** Re*(?)*write result.

Comment: does pandas method is only option to sort columns? your mentioned text file like same to my question. i don't know about pandas concept to write program.Is there any option to sort column in python?

Comment: You may think about accepting an answer to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score -1):

You may do

```
# Read
with open("filename.txt") as fic:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split() for line in fic] # read each line

# Sort
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda x:x[1])

# Write again
with open("filename.txt", "w") as fic:
    fic.writelines([" ".join(line) + "\n" for line in lines]) # write each line
```

---

Other way to read

```
lines = []
with open("filename.txt") as fic:
     for line in fic:
        line = line.rstrip().split()
        lines.append(line)
```

Other way to write

```
with open("filename.txt", "w") as fic:
    for line in lines:
        fic.write(" ".join(line) + "\n")
```

Comment: it's working fine.thanks. can you explain about below mentioned two lines....

Comment: lines = [line.rstrip().split() for line in fic]

Comment: fic.writelines([" ".join(line) + "\n" for line in lines])

Comment: @ChezhiyanSTR that is just read and write each line

Comment: i understood that two lines are read and write. i can't get knowledge of that lines......can u expand these two lines?

Comment: does below mentioned is code is right for read line?

Comment: for lines in line:
        for line in fic:
            line.rstrip()
            line.split()

Comment: @ChezhiyanSTR I've edit with more easy way to read/write. If the answer helps you, feel free to upvote, and accept it ;)

Comment: Tnq so much yaar