# Sort a CSV in Python by a column with a numerical value (and a header)

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I have a csv file called "CleanReport.csv" with some sample data, shown here:

```
Name,Color,Age
Mark,Red,9999
Bob,Red,712
Alice,Green,1
Lisa,Pink,99
Jacob,Yellow,33
Corey,Orange,44
```

And using Python I'm trying to sort by the column 'Age' (at index 2) without loosing the header column's place at the beginning. Here is my code:

```
import csv
import operator

with open('CleanReport.csv', 'r') as sortrow:
  reader = csv.reader(sortrow.readlines(), delimiter=',')
  sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(int(2)), reverse=True)

  for row in sortedlist:
    print(row)
```

I am very close. However, this is my result:

```
['Name', 'Color', 'Age']
['Mark', 'Red', '9999']
['Lisa', 'Pink', '99']
['Bob', 'Red', '712']
['Corey', 'Orange', '44']
['Jacob', 'Yellow', '333']
['Alice', 'Green', '1']
```

Where my desired result would be this:

```
['Name', 'Color', 'Age']
['Mark', 'Red', '9999']
['Bob', 'Red', '712']
['Jacob', 'Yellow', '333']
['Lisa', 'Pink', '99']
['Corey', 'Orange', '44']
['Alice', 'Green', '1']
```

As you can see it treats the contents of the third column as if they were a string, even after I cast it to int, and sorts them as if they were strings.

I also tried this code `#sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: int(x[2]), reverse=True)`, which sorts numerically as I want it to. However that only works if I remove the header row from the test data.

Is there an easier fix to this problem without having to

1. take out the header row somehow and store it in a variable
2. sort the data using `#sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: int(x[2]), reverse=True)`
3. create a new csv with the header row appended to it
4. append each row in sortedlist to the same new csv one by one using a loop?

Comment: `df.sort_values('Age')` should do the trick.

Comment: Here is code for your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63613545/4897206)

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

There's a general way to do this with just the CSV reader, and nothing else fancy, that'll get you:

1. a header
2. the "data" sorted like you want
3. variables kept to a minimum, just one, **sorted_list**

Your code looks goods, but your use of the CSV reader is a little off.  I'd definitely give the [documentation for **csv.reader**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) a read and make note of what is going on in the example, and especially just giving the reader your file, and not calling `readlines()`.  That example is also a good template for default values you don't need to specify (like, `'r'`, and `delimter=','`).

```py
import csv

sorted_list = []
with open('CleanReport.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    sorted_list.append(next(reader))  # add header as first row

    sorted_list.extend(
        sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[2]), reverse=True)
    )

for row in sorted_list:
    print(row)
```

When I run that against your sample CSV, I get:

```py
['Name', 'Color', 'Age']
['Mark', 'Red', '9999']
['Bob', 'Red', '712']
['Lisa', 'Pink', '99']
['Corey', 'Orange', '44']
['Jacob', 'Yellow', '33']
['Alice', 'Green', '1']
```

You were looking for an "easier fix" than just about the bare minimum number of steps it takes to solve this problem... it doesn't (cannot) get any easier than:

1. read/store header
2. read all "data" rows
3. sort all "data" rows
4. prepend header to sorted data rows

Also, if you all need is an automated way to sort a CSV file, I'm very fond of CSV command-line tools like csvkit's [csvsort](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvsort.html), and GoCSV's [sort](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#sort).  Both can perform basic type inference and sort your second column as the integers they are.  I'd written dozens and dozes of one-off Python scripts to handle mundane CSV processes, and there were usually small, stupid bugs.  These will always get the job done right: just one command, or pipeline of commands; no more lines and lines of Python.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving it is reading it as a dict with DictReader

```
import csv
from pprint import pp #not needed, but prints the dict better

with open('CleanReport.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f.read().splitlines(), delimiter=',')
  sorted_dict = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: int(x["Age"]), reverse=True)

  pp(sorted_dict)
```

output

```
[{'Name': 'Mark', 'Color': 'Red', 'Age': '9999'},
 {'Name': 'Bob', 'Color': 'Red', 'Age': '712'},
 {'Name': 'Lisa', 'Color': 'Pink', 'Age': '99'},
 {'Name': 'Corey', 'Color': 'Orange', 'Age': '44'},
 {'Name': 'Jacob', 'Color': 'Yellow', 'Age': '33'},
 {'Name': 'Alice', 'Color': 'Green', 'Age': '1'}]
```