# how to order values a dataframe from high to low in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
myDataTradeSWE = myDataTrade[(myDataTrade['from']=='SWE') & (myDataTrade['Year']<2015)]
myDataTradeSWE.head(10)
```

this is the code of the data frame and the data it returns the "VAL" column is the one i need to order from high to low.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to sort pandas dataframe from one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort the entire DataFrame:

```
out = myDataTradeSWE.sort_values(by='VAL', ascending=False)
```

If you want to sort only `VAL`:

```
out = myDataTradeSWE['VAL'].sort_values(ascending=False)
```