# how to Order the column values to make it more readable

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

this is example of my code. i need to reorder the values to be more readable.

```
data = {'code 1':[123, 422 , 123, 868, 422],
        'code 2':[53673, 3773, 387892, 17994, 2358]
         'Company':['GRM', 'SER', 'MEM','NOE', 'SEE']
          'Product_weight': [29,23,122,19,22]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

this is the actual table:

[image]

but i need it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: I am voting to close this question since I am pretty sure it's already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column).

Comment: Repetitive question. Multiple answers available already. Please search before posting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `sort_values`:

```
df = df.sort_values('code 1')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   code 1  code 2 Company  Product_weight
0     123   53673     GRM              29
2     123  387892     MEM             122
1     422    3773     SER              23
4     422    2358     SEE              22
3     868   17994     NOE              19
```

Comment: Good. in my dataset i was have code in zeros 00 , 0000, 0. but it show just 0 ! where did the other go?

Comment: Hmm, that sounds strange! I'm not sure why it could be happening...