# Python dataframe find closest date for each ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'SalePrice':[10,10,10,20,20,3,3,1,4,8,8],'HandoverDateA':['2022-04-30','2022-04-30','2022-04-30','2022-04-30','2022-04-30','2022-04-30','2022-04-30','2022-04-30','2022-04-30','2022-03-30','2022-03-30'],'ID': ['Tom', 'Tom','Tom','Joseph','Joseph','Ben','Ben','Eden','Tim','Adam','Adam'], 'Tranche': ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red','Red','Blue','Blue','Red','Red','Red','Red'],'Totals':[100,100,100,50,50,90,90,70,60,70,70],'Sent':['2022-01-18','2022-02-19','2022-03-14','2022-03-14','2022-04-22','2022-03-03','2022-02-07','2022-01-04','2022-01-10','2022-01-15','2022-03-12'],'Amount':[20,10,14,34,15,60,25,10,10,40,20],'Opened':['2021-12-29','2021-12-29','2021-12-29','2022-12-29','2022-12-29','2021-12-19','2021-12-19','2021-12-29','2021-12-29','2021-12-29','2021-12-29']}
```

I need to find the sent date which is closest to the HandoverDate. I've seen plenty of examples that work when you give one date to search but here the date I want to be closest to can change for every ID. I have tried to adapt the following:

```
def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min([i for i in items if i <= pivot], key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
```

And also tried to write a loop where I make a dataframe for each ID and use max on the date column then stick them together, but it's incredibly slow!

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: kindly add the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
data[['HandoverDateA', 'Sent']] = data[['HandoverDateA', 'Sent']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

out = data.loc[data['HandoverDateA']
               .sub(data['Sent']).abs()
               .groupby(data['ID']).idxmin()]
```

Output:

```
    SalePrice HandoverDateA      ID Tranche  Totals       Sent  Amount      Opened
10          8    2022-03-30    Adam     Red      70 2022-03-12      20  2021-12-29
5           3    2022-04-30     Ben    Blue      90 2022-03-03      60  2021-12-19
7           1    2022-04-30    Eden     Red      70 2022-01-04      10  2021-12-29
4          20    2022-04-30  Joseph     Red      50 2022-04-22      15  2022-12-29
8           4    2022-04-30     Tim     Red      60 2022-01-10      10  2021-12-29
2          10    2022-04-30     Tom     Red     100 2022-03-14      14  2021-12-29
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the goal is to `find the sent date which is closest to the HandoverDate`, one approach would be as follows.

First of all, create the dataframe `df` from `data` with [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then, make sure that the columns `HandoverDateA` and `Sent` are of datetime using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df['HandoverDateA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['HandoverDateA'])
df['Sent'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Sent'])
```

Then, in order to make it more convenient, create a column, `diff`, to store the absolute value of the difference between the columns `HandoverDateA` and `Sent`

```
df['diff'] = (df['HandoverDateA'] - df['Sent']).dt.days.abs()
```

With that column, one can simply sort by that column as follows

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['diff'])

[Out]:

    SalePrice HandoverDateA      ID  ... Amount      Opened diff
4          20    2022-04-30  Joseph  ...     15  2022-12-29    8
10          8    2022-03-30    Adam  ...     20  2021-12-29   18
2          10    2022-04-30     Tom  ...     14  2021-12-29   47
5           3    2022-04-30     Ben  ...     60  2021-12-19   58
8           4    2022-04-30     Tim  ...     10  2021-12-29  110
7           1    2022-04-30    Eden  ...     10  2021-12-29  116
```

and the first row is the one where `Sent` is closest to `HandOverDateA`.

With the column `diff`, one option to get the one where `diff` is minimum is with [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) as follows

```
df = df.query('diff == diff.min()')

[Out]:

   SalePrice HandoverDateA      ID Tranche  ...       Sent Amount      Opened diff
4         20    2022-04-30  Joseph     Red  ... 2022-04-22     15  2022-12-29    8
```

---

**Notes:**

- For more information on sorting dataframes by columns, [read my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66064796/7109869).