# Pandas Python Groupby Cummulative Sum Reverse

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, reverse

I have found [Pandas groupby cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum) and found it very useful. However, I would like to determine how to calculate a reverse cumulative sum.

The link suggests the following.

```
df.groupby(by=['name','day']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
```

In order to reverse sum, I tried slicing the data, but it fails.

```
df.groupby(by=['name','day']).ix[::-1, 'no'].sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()


Jack | Monday    | 10 | 90
Jack | Tuesday   | 30 | 80
Jack | Wednesday | 50 | 50
Jill | Monday    | 40 | 80
Jill | Wednesday | 40 | 40
```

EDIT:
Based on feedback, I tried to implement the code and make the dataframe larger:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': ['Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jill', 'Jill'],
     'surname' : ['Jones','Jones','Jones','Smith','Smith'],
     'car' : ['VW','Mazda','VW','Merc','Merc'],
     'country' : ['UK','US','UK','EU','EU'],
     'year' : [1980,1980,1980,1980,1980],
     'day': ['Monday', 'Tuesday','Wednesday','Monday','Wednesday'],
     'date': ['2016-02-31','2016-01-31','2016-01-31','2016-01-31','2016-01-31'],
     'no': [10,30,50,40,40],
     'qty' : [100,500,200,433,222]})
```

I then try and group on a number of columns but it fails to apply the grouping.

```
df = df.groupby(by=['name','surname','car','country','year','day','date']).sum().iloc[::-1].groupby(level=[0]).cumsum().iloc[::-1].reset_index()
```

Why is the case? I expect Jack Jones with car Mazda to be a separate cumulative quantity from Jack Jones with a VW.

Comment: @BradSolomon, unfortunately the link you reference didnt show how to include a group by. Please see my updated post and let me know if this is clearer - I cant seem to get the group by to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use double [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.groupby(by=['name','day']).sum().iloc[::-1].groupby(level=[0]).cumsum().iloc[::-1]
print (df)
                no
name day          
Jack Monday     90
     Tuesday    80
     Wednesday  50
Jill Monday     80
     Wednesday  40
```

For another column solution is simplify:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['name','day']).sum()
df['new'] = df.iloc[::-1].groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
print (df)
                no  new
name day               
Jack Monday     10   90
     Tuesday    30   80
     Wednesday  50   50
Jill Monday     40   80
     Wednesday  40   40
```

EDIT:

There is problem in second `groupby` need to append more levels - `level=[0,1,2]` means group by first `name`, second `surname` and third `car` levels.

```
df1 = (df.groupby(by=['name','surname','car','country','year','day','date'])
        .sum())
print (df1)
                                                      no  qty
name surname car   country year day       date               
Jack Jones   Mazda US      1980 Tuesday   2016-01-31  30  500
             VW    UK      1980 Monday    2016-02-31  10  100
                                Wednesday 2016-01-31  50  200
Jill Smith   Merc  EU      1980 Monday    2016-01-31  40  433
                                Wednesday 2016-01-31  40  222

df2 = (df.groupby(by=['name','surname','car','country','year','day','date'])
        .sum()
        .iloc[::-1]
        .groupby(level=[0,1,2])
        .cumsum()
        .iloc[::-1]
        .reset_index())
print (df2)
   name surname    car country  year        day        date  no  qty
0  Jack   Jones  Mazda      US  1980    Tuesday  2016-01-31  30  500
1  Jack   Jones     VW      UK  1980     Monday  2016-02-31  60  300
2  Jack   Jones     VW      UK  1980  Wednesday  2016-01-31  50  200
3  Jill   Smith   Merc      EU  1980     Monday  2016-01-31  80  655
4  Jill   Smith   Merc      EU  1980  Wednesday  2016-01-31  40  222
```

Or is possible select by names - see [groupby enhancements in 0.20.1+](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements):

```
df2 = (df.groupby(by=['name','surname','car','country','year','day','date'])
        .sum()
        .iloc[::-1]
        .groupby(['name','surname','car'])
        .cumsum()
        .iloc[::-1]
        .reset_index())
print (df2)

   name surname    car country  year        day        date  no  qty
0  Jack   Jones  Mazda      US  1980    Tuesday  2016-01-31  30  500
1  Jack   Jones     VW      UK  1980     Monday  2016-02-31  60  300
2  Jack   Jones     VW      UK  1980  Wednesday  2016-01-31  50  200
3  Jill   Smith   Merc      EU  1980     Monday  2016-01-31  80  655
4  Jill   Smith   Merc      EU  1980  Wednesday  2016-01-31  40  222
```

Comment: Thank you @jezarel - this helped, but I have another problem. Please see my edited post?