# How to calculate cumulative sum (reversed) of a Python DataFrame within given groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have a data frame (df_f) with many (n=19) columns that, if conceptually simplified looks something like this:

| Basin | (n=17 columns) | Chi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13.0 | ... | 4 |
| 13.0 | ... | 8 |
| 13.0 | ... | 2 |
| 21.0 | ... | 4 |
| 21.0 | ... | 6 |
| 38.0 | ... | 1 |
| 38.0 | ... | 7 |
| 38.0 | ... | 2 |
| 38.0 | ... | 4 |

The real data frame has around 70,000 rows and around 60 unique 'Basin' ID values (and of course other columns with numerical data, but we don't need them for this, I still want to keep them though for plotting).

**What I would like is the following:**

I want calculate the cumulative sum of the 'Chi' value, but reversed (so, going up), **AND** I want it to be reset for each Basin 'group'. So the values should be:

| Basin | (n=17 columns) | Chi_cum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13.0 | ... | 14 |
| 13.0 | ... | 10 |
| 13.0 | ... | 2 |
| 21.0 | ... | 10 |
| 21.0 | ... | 6 |
| 38.0 | ... | 14 |
| 38.0 | ... | 13 |
| 38.0 | ... | 6 |
| 38.0 | ... | 4 |

As you can see, in Chi_cum, we progressively add the Chi values going up, but we reset the sum for each 'Basin'.

I know how to do a reverse cumulative sum (`df_f['Chi_cum'] = df_f.loc[::-1, 'Chi'].cumsum()[::-1]`), but that is for the entire dataframe. Conversely, I know how to use '.groupby', but I can't seem to combine both methods of grouping and summing.

I tried doing something like:

```
df_f["Chi_cum"] = df_f.groupby(by=['Basin']).sum().iloc[::-1].groupby(level=[0]).cumsum().iloc[::-1]
```

(as inspired by [Pandas Python Groupby Cummulative Sum Reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303570/pandas-python-groupby-cummulative-sum-reverse)), but it does not work!

Could someone please help me figure this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `series` `groupby`

```
df['new'] = df.loc[::-1, 'Chi'].groupby(df['Basin']).cumsum()
df
Out[858]: 
   Basin (n=17 columns)  Chi  new
0   13.0            ...    4   14
1   13.0            ...    8   10
2   13.0            ...    2    2
3   21.0            ...    4   10
4   21.0            ...    6    6
5   38.0            ...    1   14
6   38.0            ...    7   13
7   38.0            ...    2    6
8   38.0            ...    4    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't actually add `ascending=True` or `reverse=True` to `cumsum` (!?!?), so just reverse before and after cumsum for each group:

```
df['Chi'] = df.groupby('Basin')['Chi'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1].cumsum()[::-1])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Basin  Chi
0   13.0   14
1   13.0   10
2   13.0    2
3   21.0   10
4   21.0    6
5   38.0   14
6   38.0   13
7   38.0    6
8   38.0    4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply! I will try implementing this tomorrow and check everything looks good :)

Comment: I approved the second answer since it also includes the bottom (8th) element and is a little bit more succinct! I would give you an upvote but I don't have reputation to give that out yet sadly. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Okay, that's fine! :) Note that the last item missing was just a typo in copying the output :)

Comment: I just got some new rep so I just upvoted you!