# Calculate cumulative sum while value of another column stays the same

Tags: pandas, cumulative-sum

For the following `df`, I want to calculate the cumulative sum of the column `Inst_Dist` and save as `Cumu_Dist` while the value of `WDir_Deg` stays the same. When the value in `WDir_Deg` changes, I need to restart the cumulative sum.

Therefore,

```
index | WDir_Deg | Inst_Dist | Cumu_Dist
0     | 289      | 20        | NaN
1     | 285      | 17        | NaN
2     | 285      | 19        | NaN
3     | 287      | 19        | NaN
4     | 289      | 10        | NaN
```

becomes

```
index | WDir_Deg | Inst_Dist | Cumu_Dist
0     | 289      | 20        | 20
1     | 285      | 17        | 17
2     | 285      | 19        | 36
3     | 287      | 19        | 19
4     | 289      | 10        | 10
```

My non-idiomatic (extremely slow) Python code is given below. I'd really appreciate if someone can guide me on how to make the code faster and idiomatic.

```
prev_angle = -1
curr_cumu_dist = 0
for curr_ind in df.index:
    curr_angle = df.loc[curr_ind, 'WDir_Deg']
    if prev_angle == curr_angle:
        curr_cumu_dist += df.loc[curr_ind, 'Inst_Dist']
        df.loc[curr_ind, 'Cumu_Dist'] = curr_cumu_dist
    else:
        prev_angle = curr_angle
        curr_cumu_dist = df.loc[curr_ind, 'Inst_Dist']
        df.loc[curr_ind, 'Cumu_Dist'] = curr_cumu_dist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use helper `Series` with compare `WDir_Deg` column for not equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html), [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for consecutive groups and pass it to [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
s = df['WDir_Deg'].ne(df['WDir_Deg'].shift()).cumsum()
df['Cumu_Dist'] = df.groupby(s)['Inst_Dist'].cumsum()
print (df)
   WDir_Deg  Inst_Dist  Cumu_Dist
0       289         20         20
1       285         17         17
2       285         19         36
3       287         19         19
4       289         10         10
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: WDir_Deg, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of tricky. Referencing this question/answers [Pandas groupby cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum)

I made this solution

```
df['Cumu_Dist'] = df.groupby('WDir_Deg').Inst_Dist.cumsum()
```

Which returns

```
   index  WDir_Deg  Inst_Dist  Cumu_Dist
0      0       285         17         17
1      1       285         19         36
2      2       287         19         19
3      3       289         20         20
```

This uses `pandas` version `0.23.4`

Comment: This does not work because all `WDir_Deg` values are grouped together and the change in `WDir_Deg` is neglected. I just updated the question data as well. Basically, when the `WDir_Deg` value changes, `Cumu_Dist` should start again, not continue with the previous cumulative sum.