# Pandas groupby, cumulative sum and plot by category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Having a `pandas` data frame:

```
    date        path    size
0   2019-05-10  /bar/A  3
1   2019-05-10  /bar/B  7
2   2019-05-10  /bar/C  2
3   2019-05-14  /bar/A  4
4   2019-05-14  /bar/B  8
5   2019-05-14  /bar/C  23
6   2019-05-18  /bar/A  11
7   2019-05-18  /bar/B  75
8   2019-05-18  /bar/C  32
```

I would like to `groupby` "path" and return the cumulative sum of the column "size" for each "date"

Looking at this answer:
[Pandas groupby cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum)

a simple `df.groupby(["path"])["size"].cumsum()` or `df.groupby(["path","date"])["size"].cumsum()` will not work.

In the end the cumulative sum should be plotted by date and colored by group to indicate the accumulated growth of "size" over time.

```
            /bar/A /bar/B /bar/C
2019-05-10  3      7      2
2019-05-14  7      15     26
2019-05-18  18     90     58
```

Is there any `pandas`-based solution without `seaborn` or other tools?

Comment: @splash58 Nope. This flatten everything. This will be the cumulative sum of all. I want to keep the path as categorical. In my case, this is three cumsum() results.

Comment: show the expacted result in the question

Comment: @splash58 Good point. Added expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve that pivoting the table and then applying the cumulative sum.

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values="size", index=["date"], columns=["path"], aggfunc=np.sum)
pivot = pivot.cumsum()
```

See the results, based on the example of your question:

```
df
Out[14]: 
         date    path  size
0  2019-05-10  /bar/A     3
1  2019-05-10  /bar/B     7
2  2019-05-10  /bar/C     2
3  2019-05-14  /bar/A     4
4  2019-05-14  /bar/B     8
5  2019-05-14  /bar/C    23
6  2019-05-18  /bar/A    11
7  2019-05-18  /bar/B    75
8  2019-05-18  /bar/C    32
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values="size", index=["date"], columns=["path"], aggfunc=np.sum)
pivot.cumsum()
Out[16]: 
path        /bar/A  /bar/B  /bar/C
date                              
2019-05-10       3       7       2
2019-05-14       7      15      25
2019-05-18      18      90      57
```

Comment: Close. The trick is to use `index=df.date.dt.month` for pivoting.

Comment: Well, in then you are grouping by months and not by days, right?

Comment: Indeed, in my original post I had included time in hours/mins/sec. In this case, the approach would not work.

Comment: Well, I miss your original post then. But see my last edit. Based on your example it works as expected. But if you have datetimes, instead of dates, then you can decide to just pick hours, days, months, years, it's up to you. But I think the solution I provided is what you was looking for :D

Comment: More than fine. Thank you, this works. As a workaround: `df["date"].dt.date` would be universal enough.