# How to add up current row value to the sum of subsequent values (relatively to the date corresponding to the row) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to add up current row value to the sum of subsequent values (relatively to the date corresponding to the row) in pandas ?

I'd like to take the **YTD** of the corresponding row and add the sum of all the remaining **Budget** `Values` for **2019**.
Let's suppose we are in the **4th month of 2019**.
For example, for row 0, I'd like to have 101 + the sum of the subsequent Values that are under "Budget" and "2019".
For row 1, the same logic would apply (199 + the sum of the subsequent values), etc...

**My current table is like this :**

```
    Value    Type   Date     YTD    YEP (year in projection)
0     100  Budget 2019-01-01  101                       NaN
1      50  Budget 2019-02-01  199                       NaN
2      20  Budget 2019-03-01  275                       NaN
3     123  Budget 2019-04-01  332                       NaN
4      56  Budget 2019-05-01  332                       NaN
5      76  Budget 2019-06-01  332                       NaN
6      98  Budget 2019-07-01  332                       NaN
7     126  Budget 2019-08-01  332                       NaN
8      90  Budget 2019-09-01  332                       NaN
9      80  Budget 2019-10-01  332                       NaN
10     67  Budget 2019-11-01  332                       NaN
11     87  Budget 2019-12-01  332                       NaN
12    101  Actual 2019-01-01  101                       NaN
13     98  Actual 2019-02-01  199                       NaN
14     76  Actual 2019-03-01  275                       NaN
15     57  Actual 2019-04-01  332                       NaN
```

**Desired table** :

```
     Value    Type   Date     YTD    YEP (year in projection)
0     100  Budget 2019-01-01  101                       974
1      50  Budget 2019-02-01  199                       1022
2      20  Budget 2019-03-01  275                       1078
3     123  Budget 2019-04-01  332                       1012
4      56  Budget 2019-05-01  NaN                       NaN
5      76  Budget 2019-06-01  NaN                       NaN
6      98  Budget 2019-07-01  NaN                       NaN
7     126  Budget 2019-08-01  NaN                       NaN
8      90  Budget 2019-09-01  NaN                       NaN
9      80  Budget 2019-10-01  NaN                       NaN
10     67  Budget 2019-11-01  NaN                       NaN
11     87  Budget 2019-12-01  NaN                       NaN
12    101  Actual 2019-01-01  101                       974
13     98  Actual 2019-02-01  199                       1022
14     76  Actual 2019-03-01  275                       1078
15     57  Actual 2019-04-01  332                       1012
```

Here are Excel screencaps to grasp better the calculation I'm talking about :

[screencap1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epf0H.jpg)
[screencap2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzjgF.jpg)

This Excel screencap shows well what I want to do, even though it's not rigorously the same thing (since I don't want to visually delimit the area to sum, whereas here with pandas I want to set conditions). 
Note that I know how to set conditions on Python, but here the problem is deeper, and that's precisely why i ask you people help.
Is there a function to say "***hey I want you to take the sum of the batch of numbers, but always starting from to where you are positioned***" (that's what relative position and dollars on Excel allow us to do).

Thank you !

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum) 
by inverting the DataFrame previously using `[::-1]`.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['YEP'] = ( df[::-1].loc[df['Type'].eq('Budget')]
                      .groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)
                      .Value
                      .cumsum()
                      .sub(df['Value'])
                      .add(df['YTD'])
                      .groupby(df['Date'])
                      .transform('first') )
print(df)

    Value    Type       Date  YTD     YEP
0     100  Budget 2019-01-01  101   974.0
1      50  Budget 2019-02-01  199  1022.0
2      20  Budget 2019-03-01  275  1078.0
3     123  Budget 2019-04-01  332  1012.0
4      56  Budget 2019-05-01  332   956.0
5      76  Budget 2019-06-01  332   880.0
6      98  Budget 2019-07-01  332   782.0
7     126  Budget 2019-08-01  332   656.0
8      90  Budget 2019-09-01  332   566.0
9      80  Budget 2019-10-01  332   486.0
10     67  Budget 2019-11-01  332   419.0
11     87  Budget 2019-12-01  332   332.0
12    101  Actual 2019-01-01  101   974.0
13     98  Actual 2019-02-01  199  1022.0
14     76  Actual 2019-03-01  275  1078.0
15     57  Actual 2019-04-01  332  1012.0
```

---

Then we can use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to mask when there are repeated values:

```
df[['YTD','YEP']] = df[['YTD','YEP']].mask(df.assign(year = df['Date'].dt.year)
                                             .duplicated(['Type','YTD','year']))


#df[['YTD','YEP']] = df[['YTD','YEP']].mask(df.duplicated(['Type','YTD']))
print(df)

    Value    Type       Date    YTD     YEP
0     100  Budget 2019-01-01  101.0   974.0
1      50  Budget 2019-02-01  199.0  1022.0
2      20  Budget 2019-03-01  275.0  1078.0
3     123  Budget 2019-04-01  332.0  1012.0
4      56  Budget 2019-05-01    NaN     NaN
5      76  Budget 2019-06-01    NaN     NaN
6      98  Budget 2019-07-01    NaN     NaN
7     126  Budget 2019-08-01    NaN     NaN
8      90  Budget 2019-09-01    NaN     NaN
9      80  Budget 2019-10-01    NaN     NaN
10     67  Budget 2019-11-01    NaN     NaN
11     87  Budget 2019-12-01    NaN     NaN
12    101  Actual 2019-01-01  101.0   974.0
13     98  Actual 2019-02-01  199.0  1022.0
14     76  Actual 2019-03-01  275.0  1078.0
15     57  Actual 2019-04-01  332.0  1012.0
```

Please note that this operation is carried out for each year, although this dataframe only shows 2019