# Counting culmulative occurences over time with a two-level groupby

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    country            date_added
0   United States       01/2013
1   United Kingdom      03/2014
2   Egypt               03/2014
3   United States       03/2014
4   United States       03/2014
5   United Kingdom      06/2015
6   United States       06/2015
```

And I would like a running cumulative total of each country by date, ie:

```
    date_added         country         cumulative_count
0   01/2013             United States          1
1   03/2014             United Kingdom         1
2   03/2014             Egypt                  1
3   03/2014             United States          2
4   06/2015             United Kingdom         2
5   06/2015             United States          4
```

I tried [grouping by two levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum) but .count() doesn't work (the count doesn't show up at all) whereas .size() does:

`cumulative_by_date = new_df.groupby(['date_added','country']).size()`

I don't know how to apply [this question's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum) with .size() to get a cumulative sum.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not since .size() is what is giving me a total count by time period and not .count(). Updated question and edited for clarity.

Comment: `new_df.groupby(['date_added', 'country']).size().groupby(level=1).cumsum().reset_index(name='cumulative_count')`'

Comment: Thank you, this does work. What does the second groupby (ie groupby(level=1)) do? I thought both levels would be grouped in the first .groupby()

Comment: I thought the explanation / walk-through in the second linked question was helpful.

Comment: the 3/24 united states count looks incorrect.  It should be 2 not 3

Comment: That is true, I've edited the example so it is accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the approach of the second linked question, here's a double `groupby` with `cumsum` and `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(['date_added', 'country']).size()
  .groupby(['country']).cumsum().reset_index(name='cumulative_count')
```

Output:

```
  date_added         country  cumulative_count
0    01/2013   United States                 1
1    03/2014           Egypt                 1
2    03/2014  United Kingdom                 1
3    03/2014   United States                 3
4    06/2015  United Kingdom                 2
5    06/2015   United States                 4
```

In steps:

```
# size by date and country
print(df.groupby(['date_added', 'country']).size())

# output
date_added  country       
01/2013     United States     1
03/2014     Egypt             1
            United Kingdom    1
            United States     2
06/2015     United Kingdom    1
            United States     1
```

```
# cumulative sum by country
print(df.groupby(['date_added', 'country']).size()
        .groupby(['country']).cumsum())

# output
date_added  country       
01/2013     United States     1
03/2014     Egypt             1
            United Kingdom    1
            United States     3
06/2015     United Kingdom    2
            United States     4
```

```
# reset index
print(df.groupby(['date_added', 'country']).size()
        .groupby(['country']).cumsum().reset_index(name='cumulative_count'))

# output
  date_added         country  cumulative_count
0    01/2013   United States                 1
1    03/2014           Egypt                 1
2    03/2014  United Kingdom                 1
3    03/2014   United States                 3
4    06/2015  United Kingdom                 2
5    06/2015   United States                 4
```

Comment: walk us through what is happening