# cumulative sum but keeping a column user for aggregation

Tags: python, group-by, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have a df like this one:

```
    player_profile  category    upgrade_n   level   
0   Weak            common_caddie   1       13.0    
1   Weak            common_caddie   1       25.0    
2   Weak            common_caddie   1       36.0    
3   Weak            common_caddie   1       51.0    
4   Weak            common_caddie   1       59.0    
9   Standard Player common_caddie   1       18.0    
10  Standard Player common_caddie   1       36.0    
11  Standard Player common_caddie   1       48.0
```

What I need a is cumulative by player_profile and category, but I need to keep the level column.
the final output should look like this:

```
player_profile   category        cumulative_sum   level
Weak             common_caddie   1                 13
Weak             common_caddie   2                 25
Weak             common_caddie   3                 36
Weak             common_caddie   4                 51
Weak             common_caddie   5                 59
Standard Player  common_caddie   1                 13
Standard Player  common_caddie   2                 36
Standard Player  common_caddie   3                 48
```

[I found this post but I couldn't achieve wht I wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum) (the level colum was missing).

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with the link that you show:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'profile':['w','w','w','w','m','m','m'],
                   'level': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

Then simply use `groupby` and `cumsum` or `cumcount`.

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('profile')[['level']].cumsum()
df['cumcount'] = df.groupby('profile').cumcount()+1
```

Comment: When I run this code, it seems that the resulting df is corrupted (I cannot open it or save it to a csv. Maybe you added an extra [ ] on 'level'. Anyway, it's not working